# Airflow: what do `airflow webserver`, `airflow scheduler` and `airflow worker` exactly do?

Tags: webserver, scheduler, airflow, worker

I've been working with Airflow for a while now, which was set up by a colleague. Lately I run into several errors, which require me to more in dept know how to fix certain things within Airflow.

I do understand what the 3 processes are, I just don't understand the underlying things that happen when I run them. What exactly happens when I run one of the commands? Can I somewhere see afterwards that they are running? And if I run one of these commands, does this overwrite older webservers/schedulers/workers or add a new one?

Moreover, if I for example run `airflow webserver`, the screen shows some of the things that are happening. Can I simply get out of this by pressing CTRL + C? Because when I do this, it says things like `Worker exiting` and `Shutting down: Master`. Does this mean I'm shutting everything down? How else should I get out of the webserver screen then?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Each process does what they are built to do while they are running (webserver provides a UI, scheduler determines when things need to be run, and workers actually run the tasks).

I think your confusion is that you may be seeing them as commands that tell some sort of "Airflow service" to do something, but they are each standalone commands that start the processes to do stuff. ie. Starting from nothing, you run `airflow scheduler`: now you have a scheduler running.  Run `airflow webserver`: now you have a webserver running. When you run `airflow webserver`, it is starting a python flask app.  While that process is running, the webserver is running, if you kill command, is goes down.

All three have to be running for airflow as a whole to work (assuming you are using an executor that needs workers). You should only ever had one scheduler running, but if you were to run two processes of `airflow webserver` (ignoring port conflicts, you would then have two separate http servers running using the same metadata database. Workers are a little different in that you may want multiple worker processes running so you can execute more tasks concurrently. So if you create multiple `airflow worker` processes, you'll end up with multiple processes taking jobs from the queue, executing them, and updating the task instance with the status of the task.

When you run any of these commands you'll see the stdout and stderr output in console. If you are running them as a daemon or background process, you can check what processes are running on the server.

If you ctrl+c you are sending a signal to kill the process. Ideally for a production airflow cluster, you should have some supervisor monitoring the processes and ensuring that they are always running. Locally you can either run the commands in the foreground of separate shells, minimize them and just keep them running when you need them. Or run them in as a background daemon with the `-D` argument. ie `airflow webserver -D`.

Comment: Thank you for your response, it makes some things more clear. I indeed learned that I can run a process as a daemon!

Is it correct to say that the webserver and scheduler command overwrite the old webserver and scheduler, while the worker just adds one? If for example the UI doesn't work anymore, can I simply run `airflow webserver` and it restarts? I'm looking at `ps -ajx` and see a lot of celery workers (16).. Not sure if that is okay?

Comment: The workers question is related to the fact that right now, the UI works and tasks are queued, but the worker doesn't run them. This happened after the log of one of the scripts filled up the memory, and I had to kill that process. Not sure now if tasks might be clogged or anything?

Comment: No, if you run any of the command it will start additional processes.  I go over that some in the 3rd paragraph. You should only ever have one scheduler running, so it's critical you kill that process prior to starting another.  The workers will create their own subprocesses to actually run the tasks.

As far as the why your task isn't running, hard to say without seeing the logs, perhaps make a new SO question for that, and post the logs.

Comment: Thanks. One more question related to that: how can I see how many scheduler processes are running, so I can kill them? As I think I might started multiple in that case..

Comment: That one is a little harder. The scheduler will spin off subprocesses that look similar.  I'd suggest either configuring them to run as a service so you can just start/stop the service, and allow it to ensure it stays running if the service should be started.  Leaving it running in the foreground, so you can see if its running.  Or run it through Docker.

Comment: Is there a way to completely stop airflow instead (so all of it) and just run the 3 commands again? I'm going to run it with Docker, but have to switch of the old one first

Comment: I already figured that out: `sudo service airflow-webserver stop` etc

Comment: **@Marjolein**, **@cwurtz** I was using `Linux` `screen`(s) to spawn `Airflow` `scheduler` & `webserver` (separate *screens* for each), but I never spawned any `worker`. Yet I was able to trigger `DAG`s through *UI*. But mystery doesn't end there. For applying changes in `airflow.cfg` (including changing `AIRFLOW_HOME`), i planned to kill the existing `screen`s and launch new ones. Surprisingly even after killing `webserver` `screen`, I was able to access the *UI*, then doing a `ps -aux | grep 'airflow'` made me realize i was running multiple `webserver`s (not sure about multiple `scheduler`s)

Comment: @y2k-shubham You can run multiple webservers without problem. As far as the worker I would have to guess you were using the local executor, which runs the tasks on the scheduler, so no workers are needed